# Refund Google Play apps but haven't got my money back

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

I had purchased a game on Google Play but later I realized that it was too bad, so I requested a refund. I've received a refund email from Google but I haven't received my money back. Is that a problem?

When I opened the Payment History page, it writes *Canceled* next to that game. I purchased that game using my phone bill.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**

It's not a problem. Sometimes it takes time to refund. It's happened to me earlier.

Nothing to worry about since you got your confirmation mail as also transaction is cancelled

If you wish to be doubly sure, you can call or chat with Google help from the Google Play Settings → `Help and feedback`

**Edit:** Just stumbled on this from 
[Google Play Refund help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2479637). 
If the status shows *cancelled* it means

> If the status is "Cancelled," the order was never charged and so you will not see a credit on your form of payment.

There is also a detailed table for refund timelines. Summary below :

- Credit or debit card - 3 to 5 business days
- Direct carrier billing (prepaid / pay-as-you-go) - 1 to 30 business days
- Direct carrier billing (postpaid / contract) - 1 to 2 monthly statements
- Google Play balance (gift card or credit balance or Google wallet - one business day
- Online Banking - 1 to 10 business days
- PayPal - 3 to 5 business days