# Payment deducted but app was not downloaded

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

I paid Rs.180/- for an App called "Pop Diary+Journal.  The amount was debited but the App was not downloaded.  It has not shown in Google play stores history.

The App developer said he could not help in this matter.

How to download the App or to get refund?

Comment: What stopped you from downloading? what was the error message? You can call or chat with Google help from the Google Play Settings → Help and feedback. Related question [Refund Google Play apps but haven't got my money back](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/188263). Please do not include your personal contact information on the site (now deleted). We have no use for it and no one is going to mail you a reply

Comment: Open the PlayStore app on your device, open the app page you have bought and re-download it. Once you have bought it you can download it like any free app (on the account you have bought it).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a transaction is initiated online it has 2 parts ...

- The vendor(merchant side - in this case will be google) side
- The Bank side(the bank whose Credit Card/Debit Card/Net Banking one would use)

The part that routes from the Vendor side to the respective gateway(for credit cards) and Banking portal(for Net Banking) is a normal redirection. The next process is where the actual transaction takes place ... This is the process where the Credit/Debit cards/Net Banking Accounts are debited(which involves authenticating the OTP) ... ONCE this process is completed, what lies ahead is the MOST IMPORTANT part ... the part where the Successful transaction part has to be clearly transmitted back(redirected) to the vendor side(portal) for the finality of the process.

The Issue described above is the place where the last(and the most important) part has failed ... the communication of the successful transaction back to the vendor portal which initiated this whole process ... this occurs in probability due to a request time-out ...

In such cases the vendor has no information with regard to the success(approval) of the transaction as a result they have no information of the transaction except the request time-out information. But as the transaction was successfully completed on the side of the bank with the debit and the OTP authentication leaves the funds in a suspense account waiting for the vendor to raise a credit for the same. As the Vendor has no information with regard to the success of the transaction they will not seek a credit for the same ... the bank who had moved the debit to a suspense account which holds the funds until a claim is raised will not know what to do ... except lie in wait that they may be presented with a claim any time.

Net outcome of this above situation ... is that our funds from this stale transaction will continue to rot in this suspense !!!

The only way this stands to be resolved is from the side of the Bank as the success of the transaction was fully recorded on their side.

ALL WE NEED TO DO IS ... contact the bank and raise a complaint with them of this "request time-out" issue one has faced ... They'll raise a ticket ... and investigate the same ... they'll wait for a specific time to see if any claim gets raised for this transaction with the said date, time and transaction nos. ... and even after this waiting period they do not get any claim for that particular transaction they'll finally decide that this was a case of a request time-out and subsequently issue a reversal of this transaction ... This whole exercise could take a minimum of 10 days and could differ from bank to bank.

Hope this information helps cases of request time-out get sorted out better.